# Array Modifier does not work as expected

Tags: modifiers, transforms

I am following this very simple tutorial: [Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oknULG_zLJg)

It uses an Empty constrains the rotation to a cube and then adds a plane to create the snowflake. Everything works as expected until I have to add the array modifier and my Offset Object is the above mentioned Empty.

Now I get the following unexpected result:

[image]

I did this 3 times now and I can't seem to find the reason why this does not look like this:

[image]

These are my setting:

[image]

[Download the file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/854/)

Comment: it would be easier if you upload the file

Comment: Yes they are applied for the plane object.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=854" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/854/)

Comment: the scale was not applied, @MrZak would you write the answer ?

Comment: What does apply mean and when and why do I need to apply something. I had a similar problem recently and I would appreciate if I could understand what exactly happens when I apply ? In the tutorial he also does not mention anything needs to be applied. Thank you for the answer

Comment: @MrZak link to this one : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When editing objects in Object mode, particularly scaling it, the mesh data actually isn't changed - scaling operation was performed in non-destructive way. This means that while object is displayed in viewport as scaled (and for simple operations it behaves like that too), its default scale is considered to be the non-edited one.

When scale is applied this means new values are taken into consideration as default ones. Modifiers work *as expected* with default values of transforms (and [not only modifiers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation)), so to see intended result you should apply scale.

*Note though that it's a good idea to apply transforms before proceeding to some actions with object, especially animation. Once you'll notice that it doesn't behave as expected and decide to apply transforms, it may be too late - objects won't be changed as you want them to. So plan what is expected to do with object first.*

In case of your object, this is as follows.

#### If scale is not applied

Given this snowflake:

[image: Unapplied scale]

#### If scale is applied

Everything becomes as expected:

[image: Applied scale]

To apply any kind of transforms, in Object mode press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose option from menu:

[image: Apply transforms menu]

---

There [are cases when applying transforms may be not desired](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7349/1245), but in most cases it's better to apply scale and rotation first to avoid any kind of distortions and confusion later on.

Related articles:

- [Why is it important to apply transforms](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation)
- [Applying object transforms in wiki](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html?highlight=applying%20transforms#apply-object-transformations)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much. Now I understand !