# Array modifier with Object Offest generates a large flat object which is not a copy

Tags: modifiers

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCpyt_MTRV0). At the 3 minute mark we create an Empty and make it the target of Object Offset on an Array modifier.

[image]

With Count=1 the scene looks as it does when there is no Array modifier at all

[image]

when the Count is increased, the geometry it generates doesn't look at all like the base object

[image]

What went wrong?

Comment: Try to apply the transformations (Object->Apply->All transforms menu) before the modifiers ? I think the array is making copies of the original object...

Comment: At 3:06 in the tutorial video you can see that the other modifiers are not Applied before the Array is added. Also, I tried Applying the Solidify and Subdivision and it made no difference.

Comment: I do not mean to apply the modifiers, but the transformations you do before, rotation and scaling. It seems that your "Plane" object is scaled by (0.02, 0.012, 1) and rotated by (0°,-12.743°, 0°) looking in the "Item/Transform" panel opened pressing "N" in the 3D viewport.

Comment: The magic sentence is "(...) and apply the scale (...)" just after 0:57 in the video...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

The answer is similar to this other post: [Array Modifier does not work as expected](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44646/array-modifier-does-not-work-as-expected?rq=1). The issue is about unapplied transformations.
The consequences of applying transformations are that:

- The object is rotated, then its local axes are aligned with the world axes.
- The object is scaled, then its scaling factors are reset to 1. Its dimensions are updated.
- The object origin is set to the world origin, but its vertices are not moved.

A more extensive explanation is provided here: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)

NB: In the following figures, from the original Blender file, the *Empty* object is slightly shifted along X axis to see copies when the *Array/Count* is greater than 1.

**Before applying the transformations:**
[image: Before applying]

**After applying the transformations:**
[image: After applying]